# AIX ftp file limit

Tags: ftp, aix, ulimit

I am unable to restore/ftp a file to my AIX 5.3 server. I am logged in as root:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(system) groups=2(bin),3(sys),7(security),8(cron),10(audit),11(lp)
```

I have set the fsize option in "/etc/security/limits" to "-1(unlimited)". I have confirmed this after rebooting the system, by the "ulimit -a" command:

```
# ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        unlimited
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
nofiles(descriptors) 2000
```

I have received the following error:

```
ftp> dir
200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for directory list.
-r--r--r-- 1 ftp ftp        5251072 Dec 29 08:19 DATACAPTURE.DBF
-r--r--r-- 1 ftp ftp     3292536832 Dec 28 19:45 OLTP.DBF
-r--r--r-- 1 ftp ftp     5174730752 Dec 28 19:45 STAGING.DBF
226 Transfer OK
ftp> get STAGING.DBF
200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
STAGING.DBF: short write
No space left on device/filesize limit exceeded.
426 Connection closed; transfer aborted.
226 ABOR command successful
2148154128 bytes received in 194.1 seconds (1.081e+04 Kbytes/s)
local: STAGING.DBF remote: STAGING.DBF
```

Directory size info of restore location:

```
# df -g|grep data
/dev/devddata      8.00      7.74    4%       17     1% /dprdev/data
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question. The "ulimit" options were correct. The issue was my filesystem. I initially created the logical volumes as JFS. I tried to change the "allow large files" option to "true" when mounting the logical volume in SMIT, but the system would not allow this change. I have re-created them as JFS2 and was able to create files larger than 2 gig in size on the mount points.